# Почему не срабатывает удаление элемента?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
var items = th.closest('.notificationList div').length;
if(items == 0){
    // заходит в условие
   th.closest('.notificationList').remove(); // почему-то не удаляется
}
```

**Обновление**

Предыдущий этот же элемент находит: `var items = th.closest('.notificationList div').length;`

Comment: Посмотрите в консоли, находит ли вообще элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если заходит в условие, значит, выборка элементов пустая и ничего НЕ найдено по этому селектору.